# Multidex issue in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am new comer in android studio.I am facing multidex problem in android studio. i have got many ways to solve it from internet,However i have't fix this problem. Plz help me as soon as possible,Any sort of suggestion would be accepted

Comment: I'm voting to close since this question it too broad.

Comment: I agree with @MattO'Brien, post more details, things you tried... It's too broad.

Comment: This problem got a lot of time from me.if you know how to solve it.plz let me know

Comment: It may have taken a lot of time, that's not the problem. The problem is that the question is written in such a way that nobody will be able to help you. I recommend you read this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: if you post unnecessary details and "requests" like "giff me teh codezz" , I'll probably downvote and this question will be closed.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest avoiding multidex by making your app smaller. Use this site and plugin to see where you are at http://www.methodscount.com/
Get rid of dependencies you don't actually use. 
If you are using google play services make sure you don't just add the whole thing like this: 
    `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`
Add API's selectively as described here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup